# How to get title of page in wordpress without printing it

Tags: wordpress

How to get title of page in wordpress without printing it.
I have tried wp_title but it prints the title automatically..

Answer (score 2):

Google: wordpress get post title

first result!

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title

```
<?php 
$post_title = get_the_title($ID); 
echo $post_title;
?>
```